# Force cellular data when connected to the PC over USB

Tags: debugging, windows-phone-7, cellular-network

I am debugging my Windows Phone app for some crashes that I can only reproduce when I am using cellular data connection. But when I connect my phone to the PC to debug the crash in Visual Studio, my phone is using my computers (fast) Internet connection and I can't reproduce the crashes then. This is probably somehow related to the slowness of the cellular data connectivity or something...

So is there a way to force the app to use cellular data connectivity even if the phone is connected to the PC over USB?

Or alternatively, can I somehow get some stack traces off the phone when I test it while it's disconnected from the PC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually I just turn off the wifi on my PC and on the phone. Pretty simple solution. :)

Comment: Yes, this was an easy solution :) Not so obvious when you are working on a desktop, but still viable. I would hope there would be an easier solution on the SDK side that does not require yanking the router from the wall...

Comment: No, I do the same as Andras.